# WordPress 403 issue when passing parameters in the URL

Tags: permalinks

I have been experiencing a 403 error when passing parameters in the URL of a WordPress website. Has anyone else experienced this and have a solution?

The url being passed is {{website_url}}/contact-us?enquiry_type=1

However, when removing the parameter, I dont get the 403 error.

Your input would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: From a quick search, this is the [Cerber Security Plugin](https://wpcerber.com/wp-cerber-security-8-2/). You'll probably have to configure that to be more lenient, or add exceptions for the query string parameter if you can, or ask them.

Comment: Thanks Rup! That worked. The plugin by default disallows parameters being passed in the URL.

Comment: @Rup can you leave that as an answer, identifying the plugin and suggesting it be disabled, and a link to their support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is generated by the [Cerber Security Plugin](https://wpcerber.com/wp-cerber-security-8-2/). You can add an exception on 'Antispam' under the WP Cerber menu, 'Adjust Antispam engine', 'Query whitelist'. You probably want

```
{\/contact-us\?enquiry_type=\d+}
```

for a regular expression to match any numeric enquiry_type value. The relevant documentation is here: [Configuring exceptions for the antispam engine](https://wpcerber.com/antispam-exception-for-specific-http-request/).